# List comparison and to get the Index

Tags: java, list, object, indexing, comparison

I'm having 2 lists of object, one is UI object and another one is database object,i want to compare both the list of objects(UI & database object) and to get the index of UI Object's list.

```
List<ObjectVO> listOfVOObj = new ArrayList<ObjectVO>();
List<ObjectDB> listOfDBObj = new ArrayList<ObjectDB>();


ObjectVO{
private String regNo;
private String userId;
private String name;
...
}

ObjectDB{
private String regNo;
private String userId;
..
}

listOfVOObj:
index regNo userId name
1     123   456    name1
2     2233  567    name2 
3     2234  568    name3
4     2235  569    name4
5     2236  570    name5


listOfDBObj:
index regNo userId
1     2233  567    
2     2234  568
```

i have to compare both the list and want to get the index of the records in listOfVOObj which are matching to the records in listOfDBObj.

Comment: Post some code of what you've tried so far.

Comment: Could you show us some of your code? Or is there not a single line?

Comment: sorry for not posting the question properly.

Comment: @user2507974 no problem, downvote removed : ) But you want to compare them on regNo, userId or both? And if you could post some code with your comparision, as for me it looks like two `for loops` would do the job.

Comment: thank you :) i have to compare both regNo & userId,i don't know how to do.

Comment: @user2507974 I have posted the answer for both cases if you want to store just index of the row from VOObj and indexes from both lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description it looks like this should be enough: (in the code I am comparing the objects on **regNo**)

```
List<string> indexList = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < listOfVOObj.length(); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < listOfDBObj.length(); j++)
    {
        if (listOfVOObj[i].regNo == listOfDBObj[j].regNo && listOfVOObj[i].userId == listOfDBObj[j].userId)
        {
            int  index = i + 1;
            indexList.Add(index);
        }
    }
}
```

If you would like to store indexes of both objects first you have to create new class like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
        string indexVOObj;
        string indexDBObj;

        public MyClass(string index1, string index2)
        {
                indexVOObj = index1;
                indexDBObj = index2;
        }
}
```

Then you have to use this:

```
List<MyClass> indexList = new List<MyClass>();

for (int i = 0; i < listOfVOObj.length(); i++)
{
   for (int j = 0; j < listOfDBObj.length(); j++)
   {
       if (listOfVOObj[i].regNo == listOfDBObj[j].regNo && listOfVOObj[i].userId == listOfDBObj[j].userId)
       {
           int  index1 = i + 1;
           int  index2 = j + 1;
           indexList.Add(new MyClass(index1, index2));
       }
   }
}
```